# Improve anchors in Careers

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, jobs

I rewrote my careers page and I tried to add cross links inner the page. In the Writing selection are defect id attributes. There is a tailing space which should not be there IMHO. Here as example see this link: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/rekire#article-47272%20

As you can see I need to add a `%20` which is ignored sometimes by the browsers.

A second *problem* is it is not possible to link to a Education point. Let's say I link to http://careers.stackoverflow.com/de/rekire#section-251706 that link works fine but the text is not expanded, I personally would expect that.

Maybe that ids could been improved in some way, but I think that is not nessesary. What do you think about that?

Comment: So, I cannot see the trailing spaces you are talking about. What browser/OS are you using? In Chrome 30 it looks completely normal. Also, your link to the education works fine. Is the issue that it doesn't automatically expand the section?

Comment: I just think that there should be no space at the end of the anchor. If I copy and past the url in Firefox 24 it will remove the space if I press ctrl+c. Let's say you want to copy and past such links it would not work in Firefox. (I guess that they do a trim around the link)

Comment: Reproduced in Aurora (Firefox 26) and Chrome. Compare [this anchor link (with space)](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/rekire#article-47272%20) to [this anchor link (without)](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/rekire#article-47272). Only the first link will actually take you to the anchor - if it doesn't completely ignore the space and take you nowhere.

Comment: These appear to be linking by an element's ID, too, rather than an actual anchor tag. Maybe that's a factor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed the id field on the articles, that was a mistake on our part.

As for deep linking the view side, we're punting on that right now because we don't think many people will use it as evidenced by the number of people who have ever asked for and the number of people who have voted up this post.